# Define class methods dynamically in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, method-missing

I define class methods dynamically in Rails as follows:

```
class << self
  %w[school1 school2].each do |school|
    define_method("self.find_by_#{school}_id") do |id|
        MyClass.find_by(school: school, id: id)
    end
  end
end
```

How can I use method missing to call `find_by_SOME_SCHOOL_id` without having to predefine these schools in `%w[school1 school2]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not completely clear to me what you want to achieve. If you want to call a method, you naturally have to define it first (as long as ActiveRecord does not handle this). You could do something like this:

```
class MyClass
  class << self
    def method_missing(m, *args, &block)  
      match = m.to_s.match(/find_by_school([0-9]+)_id/)
      if match
        match.captures.first
      else
        nil
      end
    end  
  end
end

puts MyClass.find_by_school1_id
puts MyClass.find_by_school2_id
puts MyClass.find_by_school22_id
puts MyClass.find_by_school_id
```

This will output:

```
1
2
22
nil
```

You could then do something with the ID contained in the method name. If you are sure that the method is defined, you can also use `send(m, args)` to call that method on an object/class. Beware though, if you do that on the same class that receives the method missing call and the method is not defined, you will get a stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks @mario. Method_missing is what I am looking for. I guess I need to parse *arg to dynamically generate methods associated with school names, then parse *block to pass an ID to these methods. Could you kindly explain how I would do this?

Comment: @AdamNYC Not exactly. What you need to parse is the `m` parameter. This contains the name of the called method, as a symbol. In my example I extract the ID from the method name using regular expressions. You can instead of course just check if the method exists already with `defined?` and then use `define_method` with `m` to generate that method if it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend return the super unless you have a match

```rb
class MyClass
  class << self
    def method_missing(m, *args, &block)  
      match = m.to_s.match(/find_by_school([0-9]+)_id/)
      match ? match.captures.first : super
    end  
  end
end
```